# Json not mapping properly in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Here is a json document that I wanted to map it to C# poco classes. I wrote some classes but they didn't work. I got null in my result object. Any ideas?

I used Newtonsoft's json converter.

```
{
  "retrieval-response":{
  "cdata":{
   "identifier":"777400",
   "document-count":"62"
  },
  "index":"10",
  "count":"25"
  }
}
```

C# map classes;

```
public class result
{
    [JsonProperty("retrieval-response")]
    public aResult res { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }

}

public class aResult
{
    public cdata data { get; set; }
}

public class cdata
{
    [JsonProperty("identifier")]
    public string identif { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("document-count")]
    public string count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Mapping? Mapping how?

Answer (score 2):

You model is wrong. Try this:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("retrieval-response")]
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("cdata")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }

    public int Index { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("identifier")]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("document-count")]
    public string Count { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize it with the following line:

```
var myResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(json);
```

Please note that I've also wrote your property and class names in pascal case. These are the [naming conventions from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).